# Find the supremum and infimum of {x $\in$ [0,1]: x $\notin$ $\mathbb Q$}. Prove why your assertions are correct

Tags: rational-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Ok I am lost from this question. Does that mean $x$ can only be $0$ or $1$? And it can't be any rational?

Comment: That means $x$ is an irrational in the interval $[0,1]$. Use the fact that the irrationals in $[0,1]$ are dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: $x$ is any irrational number between 0 and 1.

Comment: What is dense???

Comment: @Tim Basically that every element in $[0,1]$ can be approached by irrationals. In particular this is the case for the endpoints $0$ and $1$. Hence, for example, the supremum $\alpha$ cannot be less than $1$. Indeed, if it were the case, then there would be an irrational in $(\alpha,1]$ and so $\alpha$ would not be an upper bound for your set. On the other hand, $1$ is clearly an upper bound, and because of the preceding discussion it is the least upper bound, that is, $\alpha=1$.

Comment: If the question meant that $x$ could only be $0$ or $1$, it would be $x\in\{0,1\}$. But what is written is $x\in[0,1]$; brackets instead of curly braces.

Comment: @Tim a set $A$ is called dense (in the space $X$) if every point in $X$ is either in $A$ or is a limit point of $A$.  So the irrationals are dense in the reals, because every real number is either an irrational or is arbitrarily close to one.

Answer (score 1):

I show that $1$ is the supremum of the set $A := \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, and you may try the infimum case.

The proof relies on the fact that between every two real numbers there is some irrational. (Because $\mathbb{R}$ is the closure of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.)

By definition, it is equivalent to prove that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $x \in A$ such that $1 - \varepsilon < x \leq 1$. But this is true, since between any two real numbers there is some irrational.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean x can only be 0 or 1? And it can't be any rational?

No, it means $x$ is any irrational between $0$ and $1$.

$\{x\in [0;1]: x\notin \Bbb Q\}$ is: the set of numbers from the real interval $0$ to $1$ inclusive, such that these numbers are also not in the rationals.

Now, find the supremum of this set.   First, what is *your* definition of a supremum?

> A set $E ⊂  R$  is bounded above iff $∃  b ∈  R$  s.t. $a \leq b, ∀  a ∈  E$ ($b$ is an upper bound for $E$)

No, that is not the definition of supremum.  That is the definition of upper bound.  A supremum is a special kind of upper bound.  It's the *least* such.

A value $s\in R$ is the supremum of $E$ if $\;\nexists b\in R: \forall a\in E: ((a\leq b) \wedge (b< s)\wedge (a\leq s))$

Now, can you find such an upper bound for your set?  Can you show that this is the supremum.

Comment: A set E $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded above iff $\exists$ b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. a < b, $\forall$ a $\in$ E (b is an upper bound for E)

Comment: @Tim No, that is not the definition of supremum.  A supremum is the *least* upper bound of the set.

Comment: oh, a real number s is said to be the least upper bound (L.U.B.) of a non empty set E $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ iff s is an upper bound for E and if b is any upper bound for E, then b $\geq$ s. s is the. L.U.B. Notation: s = sup E

Comment: @Tim, yes.  Now what number fits that definition for $\{x\in[0;1]\mid x\notin\Bbb Q\}$?  What is the smallest real number that is an upper bound of the set?

Comment: Looks like 1 has to be the sup? And the inf has to be some irrational number? Or 0?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $[0,1]$ is an interval on the real line which contains all of the numbers between $0$ and $1$ including $0$ and $1$.

Now, $\{x \in [0,1] \mid x \not \in \Bbb Q \}$ is a subset of the interval $[0,1]$, but it is the subset we get by removing all of the rational points from $[0,1]$.

So, you have to think about all of the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$, and find the supremum and infimum of that set.

We know since $\Bbb R$ is **complete** that since the set in question is bounded above by $5$, for example, it has a *least upper bound* which is the supremum.  Do you know what the smallest upper bound is?  It is $1$, since $1$ is larger than every irrational in $[0,1]$ but it is smaller than every upper bound of the irrationals in $[0,1]$ (why?).

Now you have to find the infimum of the set of irrationals in $[0,1]$ on your own.  If you get stuck, let me know.

Comment: So the supremum is 1?

Comment: @Tim Yes. I'd like for you to tell me why.  You have to answer two questions to tell me why.  Is $1$ an upper bound for every irrational number in $[0,1]$?  Also, if you have any other upper bound $b$ for every irrational in $[0,1]$, is $1 \leq b$?  Why?

Comment: The supremum is always bigger than infimum

Comment: @Tim That's true, but not relevant to the two questions I asked you.  Keep thinking about them.